# Zend_Form not valid but no error messages

Tags: zend-framework, validation, zend-form

i have a strange Problem with one of my Zend_Forms: `isValid()` correctly states that my form isn't valid but i do not get any error messages. How could that happen?

Heres the code, nothing special here. `$data` is an array of post data. The problem occurs when no file is sended.

```
    $form = $this->getForm('Foto');
    if(!$form->isValid($data)) {
        var_dump( $form->getErrors() ); die;
        return false;
    }
```

`getForm()` initializes the form if not allready done. The form itself is pretty straight forward.

```
class Media_Forms_Foto extends Zend_Form
{
    /**
     * Initializer function. Setup forms fields.
     */
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('add Image');
        $this->setAction('media/gallery/addImage');

        $this->addElement('Hidden', 'gallery', array(
            'filters'    => array(),
            'validators' => array('Digits'),
            'required'   => false,
            'label'      => '',
        ));

        $this->addElement('File', 'foto', array(
            'required'      => true,
            'destination'   => ROOT_PATH .'public/upload/tmp/',
            'label'         => 'Foto',
            'validators'    => array(
                new Zend_Validate_File_IsImage(array(
                    'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'
                ))
            ),
            'maxFileSize'   => 2097152,
        ));

        $this->addElement('Submit', 'add', array(
            'required' => false,
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'add Foto',
        ));

        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
    ["gallery"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    ["foto"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    ["add"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
}
```

Comment: Does anything output with `getErrorMessages`?

Comment: Quick question, where is your $data coming from? Have you tried outputting that? I usually do:
(from the controller) $this->getRequest()->getPost(); to get the post data, I know it´s a silly question, but your zend_form looks pretty straight to me so I´m trying to look for other problems that might be causing the validation not to "work".

Answer (score -4):

Are you using the jquery form plugin by any chance? if so, try using the iframe mode to upload files:

```
var options = {
    url: '/test/upload',
    success: function(response) {
    },
    beforeSubmit: disableSubmitButtons,
    iframe: true,
    dataType : 'json'
};

$('#testForm').ajaxForm(options);
```